# Services 7.3 - Simple Resource Example works only with GET not with POST from Poster

Tags: services

I created a very simple test service here is the code, for some reason only GET works with it in Firefox Poster, but POST returns a 404 Controller not found. Any tips?
Here is what works
http://mysite.com/services/myendpoint/mytest/retrieve/

with parameter of 
id = 1

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_services_resources().
 */
function mytest_services_resources() {
  return array(
   'mytest' => array(
     'retrieve' => array(
       'help' => 'Retrievs a test',
       'callback' => '_mytest_retrieve',
       'args' => array(
         array(
           'name' => 'id',
           'type' => 'int',
           'description' => 'The id of the test to get',
           'source' => array('path' => '0'),
           'optional' => FALSE,
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
  );
}

/**
 * Callback for creating  resources.
 *
 * @param object $data
 * @return object
 */
function _mytest_retrieve($id) {
  return "READY TESTING";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need separate callbacks for each of the CRUD operations. You've only implemented 'retrieve', which is the GET callback, you need to implement a 'create' callback for POST to function.

Reading the docs really helps:
https://drupal.org/node/783460

Comment: Thanks it took me a while to realize I needed an "Action" instead of a CRUD REST resource: https://drupal.org/node/783254 
The best reference was the existing service calls for user, node and system...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? An Action is used to modify a Resource overall, as in all resources of a given type (like a Content Type). A Targeted Action is used to modify "one field" of a multi-component (multi-field) an individual resource (like a single node), whereas the Update portion of the CRUD pattern is for modifying all the fields of an individual resource.

Comment: All I want is that a user sends my site some text and I send back some data. No nodes, no CRUD, just spitting back some data based on some calcs. I managed to make this work via an action, and it works like magic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: After a custom service, when I tried to access it, it return 404 error message. I've tried it even after clear the catch. How to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

you can't POST for any retrieve method.

Post is only for actions, and create methods.

you can read WAY more about it here.
http://drupal.org/node/783254

Comment: Thanks Kyle, yes I found that post after I posted this question. Great stuff! I settled for now with a simple action. Love Services.